# LibSVM classification to tree

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka, libsvm

I have classified my dataset with libSVM in WEKA software. libSVM gives me the best results until now.
Is it possible to see the results on a tree view (for example like J48 tree)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The learned model is specific to the machine learning algorithm used and cannot be transformed into another one. If you want to see a tree, you have to use one of the tree-building algorithms.

Comment: So how can i see practical results of the svm classifier and not just confusion matrix or accuracy?

Comment: There's more information on that [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Making+predictions).